# Improve priority of mplayer-pulseaudio-Xorg combination

Tags: xorg, pulse-audio, mplayer, priority

I'm often having mplayer running on the side (e.g. watching television). However, this occasionally doesn't run too smoothly (granted, the CPU and GPU are also a bit weak).

I've already running pulseaudio with rtkit at an elevated priority, but that didn't seem to help much. On contrary, recently I have more often than before to kill pulseaudio and restart the player because apparently when player and pulseaudio get out of sync that causes the weirdest distortions.

I blame mostly Chrome for this. The webbrowser is a memory hog, and memory is also limited on my system. And we all know how systems react when they need to swap... (And in fact, having switched back to Firefox does seem to make things better)

Anyway, now for my main question: is there any use in increasing the priority of mplayer/Xorg/pulseaudio for this? Or will this make things even worse (since Chrome also hits badly on the GPU and thus Xorg)? Or is the key to run chrome somehow in a memory-limited mode, and disable swap etc.?

What do you do to have a flawless video playback while running ressource-hungry applications such as chrome? After all, sooner or later Firefox will probably become as hungry as chrome...